# Continuous Function Example Problem (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm supposed to give an example of a continuous increasing function $f:(0,1) \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f((0,1))$ is a closed interval. In all honesty, I'm pretty stumped. I've considered playing with the tangent function but the results leave me with a non-closed interval. Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Does increasing mean strictly increasing? Or does it mean non-decreasing?

Comment: No. The example I'm working with just says increasing, so it doesn't have to be strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it just has to be non-decreasing, try
$$
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0<x< \frac14 \\
2(x-\frac14) & \frac14 \leq x \leq \frac34 \\
1 & \frac34 < x < 1 \end{array}\right.
$$
which is increasing (but not strinctly increasing) and maps $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the constant function which is clearly increasing (nondecreasing).

Comment: The only problem with that is then f((0,1)) would not be a closed interval, it would be a singleton set.

Comment: If your definition of closed interval meaning $[a, b]$ and $a<b$, then yes my example will not work. Otherwise, I think it's okay.